# Ajuda com innerHTML no Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

estou tentando adicionar uma variavel que contem um elemento html no meu arquivo html, estou tentando usar o innerHTML += minhavar, o problema é que, eu tenho dois elementos para serem adicionados, um iframe e um paragrafo, quando adiciono iframe vai de boa, mas o paragrafo não adiciona.

```
function inserir() {
  let nomeVideo = document.querySelector('#nome-video').value;
  let linkVideo = document.querySelector('#link-video').value;
  let itemVideo = `<div class="items-video">
                   <iframe src="${linkVideo}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
                   <p>${nomeVideo}</p>
                  </div>`;

  document.querySelector('#conteudo-videos').innerHTML += itemVideo;
}


<!--html-->
<div class="container-items" id="conteudo-videos">
</div>
```

Oque eu posso estar fazendo errado ?? lembrando que estou começando agora no javascript, então perdoem a noobise.

Comment: Tinha esquecido de fechar o iframe

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, tome cuidado com os [`Template Literals`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals), o suporte dos Browsers ainda é pequeno.

Então no lugar do `Template Literals` irei utilizar o Handlebars, apenas para melhorar a compatibilidade do seu codigo.

Mas o problema, era que você está esquecendo de fechar o seu iframe.

```js
var templateVideo = document.querySelector('#template-video');
var inserirVideo = document.querySelector('#inserir-video');
var nomeVideo = document.querySelector('#nome-video');
var linkVideo = document.querySelector('#link-video');
var conteudoVideo = document.querySelector('#conteudo-videos');

var template = Handlebars.compile(templateVideo.innerHTML);
var parser = new DOMParser();

function inserir() {
  var modelo = {
    linkVideo: linkVideo.value, 
    nomeVideo: nomeVideo.value
  };
  var htmlVideo = template(modelo);
  var itemVideo = parser.parseFromString(htmlVideo, "text/html").firstChild
  conteudoVideo.appendChild(itemVideo);
}

inserirVideo.addEventListener("click", inserir);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.8/handlebars.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Inserir Video</legend>
  <label>
    Nome:
    <input id="nome-video" type="text" />
  </label>
  <label>
    Link:
    <input id="link-video" type="text" />
  </label>
  <input id="inserir-video" type="button" value="Inserir" />
</fieldset>

<div class="container-items" id="conteudo-videos">
</div>

<script id="template-video" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="items-video">
   <iframe src="{{linkVideo}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   <p>{{nomeVideo}}</p>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Dessa eu não sabia @TobiasMesquita, muito obrigado por ajudar

Answer (score 1):

Vi que o erro no seu código é a falta do fechamento da tag iframe.
Fiz um teste aqui e deu certo, segue:

```js
function inserir() {
            let nomeVideo = "Teste Template String"
            let linkVideo = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/mKcZVZNDQPE"
            let itemVideo =
                `
                <div class="items-video">
                   <iframe src="${linkVideo}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                   <p>${nomeVideo}</p>
                </div>
                `;

            document.querySelector('#conteudo-videos').innerHTML += itemVideo;
        }

        inserir()
```

```html
<div class="container-items" id="conteudo-videos">
    </div>
```

Com relação ao comentário sobre a compatibilidade da template String, realmente. O IE nem o Opera implementaram ainda.

Entretanto, se a compatibilidade for um ponto crucial para seu problema, sugiro dar uma olhada no Transpiler [BabelJS](https://babeljs.io/).

O que ele faz é fazer um "Downgrade" do seu código escrito em ES6+ (mais novas funcionalidade) para o javascript ES5-, código que todos os browsers entedem.