# Chamar data pelo javascript

Tags: javascript, data, time

Estou colocando a data no site com esse código que esta funcionando, porem esse script tem que estar dentro do elemento HTML em que a data vai aparecer.

Como eu posso mudar esse script para que a data apareça em uma `DIV` identificada pelo seu `ID`?

```js
var now = new Date();
var mName = now.getMonth() +1 ;
var dName = now.getDay() +1;
var dayNr = now.getDate();
var yearNr=now.getYear();
if(dName==1) {Day = "Domingo";}
if(dName==2) {Day = "Segunda-feira";}
if(dName==3) {Day = "Terça-feira";}
if(dName==4) {Day = "Quarta-feira";}
if(dName==5) {Day = "Quinta-feira";}
if(dName==6) {Day = "Sexta-feira";}
if(dName==7) {Day = "Sábado";}
if(mName==1){Month = "Janeiro";}
if(mName==2){Month = "Fevereiro";}
if(mName==3){Month = "Março";}
if(mName==4){Month = "Abril";}
if(mName==5){Month = "Maio";}
if(mName==6){Month = "Junho";}
if(mName==7){Month = "Julho";}
if(mName==8){Month = "Agosto";}
if(mName==9){Month = "Setembro";}
if(mName==10){Month = "Outubro";}
if(mName==11){Month = "Novembro";}
if(mName==12){Month = "Dezembro";}
if(yearNr < 2000) {Year = 1900 + yearNr;}
else {Year = yearNr;}
var todaysDate =(" " + "São Paulo, " + dayNr + " de " + Month + " de " + Year  +  " - " + Day  );

document.write('   '+todaysDate);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<!-- A data entraria nesta DIV -->
<div id="todaysDate">"  "</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Já tentou algo tipo no final do código, document.getElementById('todaysDate').innerHTML = todaysDate

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Ajuda com innerHTML no Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/204322/ajuda-com-innerhtml-no-javascript)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Henriquuepedro e Darlei Fernando Zilmer, já alterei aqui e está ok

Answer (score 5):

### Inserindo conteúdo no DOM:

Para inserir qualquer texto no DOM, você pode fazer uso de técnicas como `textContent`, *append*, e outras. Como só queremos inserir um texto com a data atual formatada, irei usar o `textContent`.

Você pode fazer assim:

```js
// Selecionamos o elemento:
const element = document.querySelector('#el')

// Inserimos qualquer texto:
element.textContent = 'Olá, mundo!'
```

```html
<div id="el"></div>
```

---

### Em relação à forma de gerar a *string* formatada da data:

Uma forma interessante de se fazer isso sem criar essa enorme quantidade de `if`s, que tornam o código extremamente *poluído* é usar `array`s:

```js
// Criamos a instância da data:
const date = new Date()

// Capturamos o dia do mês e o ano:
const day = date.getDate()
const year = date.getFullYear()

// Capturamos o dia da semana:
const weekDayList = ['Domingo', 'Segunda-feira', 'Terça-feira', 'Quarta-feira', 'Quinta-feira', 'Sexta-feira', 'Sábado']
const weekDayString = weekDayList[date.getDay()]

// Capturamos o mês:
const monthList = ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro']
const monthString = monthList[date.getMonth()]

// Criamos a string final:
const dateString = `São Paulo, ${day} de ${monthString} de ${year} - ${weekDayString}`

// Inserimos a data na `div#date`:
document.querySelector('#date').textContent = dateString
```

```html
<div id="date"></div>
```

#### Explicação:

Tendo em vista que os métodos [`getDay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) e [`getMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) retornam um valor com índice zero, podemos criar uma lista mapeando o número retornado por esses métodos para o seu correspondente nome.

**Exemplo:**

Se `getDay` retornasse `3`, levando em conta que o método `getDay` retorna o dia da semana com índice zero, poderíamos concluir que isso iria corresponder a "Quarta-feira", já que:

- `0` ⇒ Domingo;
- `1` ⇒ Segunda-feira;
- `2` ⇒ Terça-feira;
- `3` ⇒ Quarta-feira;
- Demais dias da semana...

Veja funcionando:

```js
const weekDayList = ['Domingo', 'Segunda-feira', 'Terça-feira', 'Quarta-feira', 'Quinta-feira', 'Sexta-feira', 'Sábado']

// Asumindo que `date.getDay` retorne 3:
const returnValue = 3

// O output abaixo deve mostrar "Quarta-feira":
console.log(returnValue, '⇒', weekDayList[returnValue])
```

E esse mesmo comportamento vale para `getMonth`, que retorna o mês do ano com índice a partir do zero.

---

Em suma, o JavaScript é uma linguagem extremamente poderosa que te permite fazer coisas incríveis. Esse é um exemplo de como a flexibilidade da linguagem pode te ajudar a simplificar o código. Isso sim é facilitar!! :)

Answer (score 3):

Se você já utiliza javascript puro, não há a necessidade nenhuma de utilizar o Jquery, veja que não há a necessidade de utilizar o objeto global window em onload, comumente as pessoas o utilizam window.onload por não saber que podem funcionar sem o window.

segue um exemplo:

```
<html>

<script>
onload = function(){
  var now = new Date();
  var mName = now.getMonth() +1 ;
  var dName = now.getDay() +1;
  var dayNr = now.getDate();
  var yearNr=now.getYear();
  if(dName==1) {Day = "Domingo";}
  if(dName==2) {Day = "Segunda-feira";}
  if(dName==3) {Day = "Terça-feira";}
  if(dName==4) {Day = "Quarta-feira";}
  if(dName==5) {Day = "Quinta-feira";}
  if(dName==6) {Day = "Sexta-feira";}
  if(dName==7) {Day = "Sábado";}
  if(mName==1){Month = "Janeiro";}
  if(mName==2){Month = "Fevereiro";}
  if(mName==3){Month = "Março";}
  if(mName==4){Month = "Abril";}
  if(mName==5){Month = "Maio";}
  if(mName==6){Month = "Junho";}
  if(mName==7){Month = "Julho";}
  if(mName==8){Month = "Agosto";}
  if(mName==9){Month = "Setembro";}
  if(mName==10){Month = "Outubro";}
  if(mName==11){Month = "Novembro";}
  if(mName==12){Month = "Dezembro";}
  if(yearNr < 2000) {Year = 1900 + yearNr;}
  else {Year = yearNr;}
  var todaysDate =(" " + "São Paulo, " + dayNr + " de " + Month + " de " + Year  +  " - " + Day  );

document.getElementById("todaysDate").innerHTML = todaysDate;
}
</script>

<body>
<!-- A data entraria nesta DIV -->
<div id="todaysDate"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente da seguinte forma com `JavaScript` puro. Lembre-se, no entanto, que se você usar `jQuery` pode facilitar na questão estética do seu código, outras bibliotecas de tratamento e tradução de datas também, sempre é bom verificar se está usando um `framework` que já contenha essas funcionalidades incluídas, vai poupar todos esses `ifs`.

```js
var now = new Date();
var mName = now.getMonth() +1 ;
var dName = now.getDay() +1;
var dayNr = now.getDate();
var yearNr=now.getYear();
if(dName==1) {Day = "Domingo";}
if(dName==2) {Day = "Segunda-feira";}
if(dName==3) {Day = "Terça-feira";}
if(dName==4) {Day = "Quarta-feira";}
if(dName==5) {Day = "Quinta-feira";}
if(dName==6) {Day = "Sexta-feira";}
if(dName==7) {Day = "Sábado";}
if(mName==1){Month = "Janeiro";}
if(mName==2){Month = "Fevereiro";}
if(mName==3){Month = "Março";}
if(mName==4){Month = "Abril";}
if(mName==5){Month = "Maio";}
if(mName==6){Month = "Junho";}
if(mName==7){Month = "Julho";}
if(mName==8){Month = "Agosto";}
if(mName==9){Month = "Setembro";}
if(mName==10){Month = "Outubro";}
if(mName==11){Month = "Novembro";}
if(mName==12){Month = "Dezembro";}
if(yearNr < 2000) {Year = 1900 + yearNr;}
else {Year = yearNr;}
var todaysDate =(" " + "São Paulo, " + dayNr + " de " + Month + " de " + Year  +  " - " + Day  );

document.getElementById('todaysDate').innerHTML = todaysDate;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<!-- A data entraria nesta DIV -->
<div id="todaysDate">"  "</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Exemplo com `jQuery`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <!-- A data entraria nesta DIV -->
        <div id="todaysDate">"  "</div>
    </body>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            var now = new Date();
            var mName = now.getMonth() +1 ;
            var dName = now.getDay() +1;
            var dayNr = now.getDate();
            var yearNr=now.getYear();
            if(dName==1) {Day = "Domingo";}
            if(dName==2) {Day = "Segunda-feira";}
            if(dName==3) {Day = "Terça-feira";}
            if(dName==4) {Day = "Quarta-feira";}
            if(dName==5) {Day = "Quinta-feira";}
            if(dName==6) {Day = "Sexta-feira";}
            if(dName==7) {Day = "Sábado";}
            if(mName==1){Month = "Janeiro";}
            if(mName==2){Month = "Fevereiro";}
            if(mName==3){Month = "Março";}
            if(mName==4){Month = "Abril";}
            if(mName==5){Month = "Maio";}
            if(mName==6){Month = "Junho";}
            if(mName==7){Month = "Julho";}
            if(mName==8){Month = "Agosto";}
            if(mName==9){Month = "Setembro";}
            if(mName==10){Month = "Outubro";}
            if(mName==11){Month = "Novembro";}
            if(mName==12){Month = "Dezembro";}
            if(yearNr < 2000) {Year = 1900 + yearNr;}
            else {Year = yearNr;}
            var todaysDate =(" " + "São Paulo, " + dayNr + " de " + Month + " de " + Year  +  " - " + Day  );

            $('#todaysDate').text(todaysDate);
        });

    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Você diz que "jQuery facilitaria" nesse caso. Como você sugere isso? Não consigo enxergar o benefício que você menciona.

Comment: Beneficio funcional não, me refiro só a escrita do código mesmo

Comment: 90% do código acima é feito com `if`/`else` e a API de datas do JavaScript. Reitero que não consigo enxergar uma grande melhoria com o uso do jQuery. Por isso a dúvida. :)

Comment: Realmente, eu considero mais como um "atalho" para algumas coisas e em alguns casos um script a mais pra pesar no carregamento